# A Combinatorics Problem: What's Wrong With My Method

Tags: combinatorics

I've encountered a combinatorics problem, which I got wrong. I'm hoping to get 2 things in this answer:

1. An explanation of why my method is wrong.
2. How the textbook got to the correct method.

The problem I'm doing is problem 3(c).

[image: problem_statement]

The correct answer is $27~941~760$ ways.

I will write the sick man as "c" and an empty spot as "e".

I started with the situation with "c e", where there will be one sick man, and one empty spot. In this situation, there will be $(13 \cdot 12 \cdot 11 \cdot 10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7)$ ways to distribute everyone else into their seats. Also, in this situation, there will only be $2$ positions where this is possible. Either, the sick person could sit on the left most seat, or the rightmost seat. So there are a total of $2 \cdot (13 \cdot 12 \cdot 11 \cdot 10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7)$ in this scenario.

Then there's the situation with "e c e". The number of ways we can't move this is $3!$. But we can't have something like "c e e" or "e e c", or the sick person won't be separate to his or her neighbour). The are a total of $4$ ways for this arrangement to occur, so we need to subtract that. Then why multiply this by $11$ because this is how many times it can be moved across to, and then add $2$. Then multiply to $(11 \cdot 10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5)$.

I repeated this and got:

$$2 \cdot (13 \cdot 12 \cdot 11 \cdot 10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7)+((3!-4)12+2)(12  \cdot 11  \cdot 10  \cdot 9  \cdot 8 \cdot 7  \cdot 6))+((4!-2  \cdot 3!)11+2)(11 \cdot 10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5))+((5!-2 \cdot 4!)10+2)(10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4))+((6!-2 \cdot 5!)9+2)(9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4  \cdot 3))+((7!-2 \cdot 6!)8+2)(8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2))+((8!-2 \cdot 7!)7+2)(7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5  \cdot 4  \cdot 3  \cdot 2  \cdot 1))$$

Which gave a wrong answer.

Why is the wrong? I know for starters that in the the step for "e c e", it doesn't ensure that the first non sick person sits right next to "e", therefore resulting in over counting. But I have a feeling there are more errors to this than that, and I would like an explanation of these errors.

Can you please explain this at the level of a high school student? I have a very cursory understanding of combinatorics; literally the only $2$ principles I know are the multiplication and addition principle.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please type your question rather than posting a link since links may be deleted.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the "c e" case you've made a slight error -- there are $12$ remaining seats for the next person to sit, not $13$.

In the "e c e" case I find it difficult to follow your reasoning. In particular I see no reason to introduce a $3!$ factor -- the "e c e" arrangement is already set. Furthermore there are $12$, not $11$, places to slide this arrangement to (the middle seat "c" can be in any of seats 2 through 13).

Thus the answer should be $2\cdot(12\cdot11\cdot10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7\cdot6)+12\cdot(11\cdot10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7\cdot6\cdot5)$ which gives the textbook's answer

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you left out all the cases that look like

`c......eeeee.e.e`

for instance, where the sick guy is more than one step away from any of the healthy people.

Comment: No I haven't, I just didn't write them out (sorry about that). I've included them in my final solution. And anyway, I overcounted by a significant amount. Can you please explain why that is? Thanks.

Comment: Nope. Your job, as the questioner, is to take the time to make your method very clear to the reader, who is volunteering time to try to help you. You might try solving (by explicitly writing out cases) a much simpler problem like one sick person, 2 healthy people, 6 seats, and compare your approach (applied to that problem) with the correct answer (derived by enumeration). Because there are only about 100 possible seating cases, and many of these will not be "valid", enumeration is actually feasible for a problem of this size. If you add such an example, and solution, helping you will be easy.